# Работа со словарями

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу доработать код. Нужно организовать работу с файлом, содержащим следующие сведения об игрушках: код, наименование, фирма-производитель,
возрастное назначение, цена. Поиск осуществлять по следующим
параметрам:

1. название;
2. фирма-производитель и возрастное назначение (диапазон);
3. название, при этом определить игрушку с минимальной ценой и с
   максимальной.

```
R = dict()
code = input("Введите код товара: ")
name = input("Введите наименование товара: ")
firm = input("Введите фирму-производитель: ")
age = input("Введите возрастное ограничение: ")
price = input("Введите стоимость: ")
R [k] = (code, name, firm, age, price)
for k in range(N):
    if d in R [k] : print(R[k])
f = open ('terxt.txt','w') #Запись файла
for k in R:
    f.write(str(k),+'\n')
    f.close()
Q=dict()
for line in f:
    Q[k] = line [:-1]
```

Код явно неправильный и требует доработок. Прошу помочь чем кто может. Являюсь новичком, поэтому многого могу не понимать. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам лучше подойдет класс. Вот пример программы:

```
class Toy:
    def __init__(self, code,name,firm,age,price):
        self.code=code
        self.name=name
        self.firm=firm
        self.age=age
        self.price=price

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)+' Название: '+self.name+' Фирма: '+self.firm+' Возраст: '+str(self.age)+' Цена: '+str(self.price)

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getCode(self):
        return self.code

    def getFirm(self):
        return self.firm

    def getAge(self):
        return self.age

    def getPrice(self):
        return self.price


def readToys(filename):
    f=open(filename, "r")
    res=[]
    for line in f:
        values=line.split(';')
        toy=Toy(int(values[0]),values[1],values[2],int(values[3]),int(values[4]))
        res.append(toy)
    return(res)

def searchName(toys,name):
    flag=0
    for toy in toys:
        if toy.getName()==name:
            print(toy)
            flag=1
    if flag==0:
        print('Товаров не найдено')

def searchFirmAge(toys,firm,a,b):
    flag=0
    for toy in toys:
        if toy.getFirm()==firm and toy.getAge()>=a and toy.getAge()<=b:
            print(toy)
            flag=1
    if flag==0:
        print('Товаров не найдено')

def searchMaxName(toys,name):
    flag=0
    for toy in toys:
        if toy.getName()==name:
            if flag==0:
                    tmax=toys[0]
                    tmin=toys[0]
                    flag=1
            else:
                if tmax.getPrice()<toy.getPrice():
                    tmax=toy
                if tmin.getPrice()>toy.getPrice():
                    tmin=toy
    if flag==0:
        print('Товаров не найдено')
    else:
        print('Максимальная цена: ',tmax)
        print('Минимальная цена: ',tmin)


toys=readToys("in.txt")

state=-1
while state!=0:
    print("[1] - Поиск по названию")
    print("[2] - Поиск по фирме и диапазону возрастов")
    print("[3] - Минимальная и максимальная цена с одинаковым названием")
    print("[0] - Выход")
    state=int(input("Выбор: "))
    if state==1:
        name=input("Введите имя: ")
        searchName(toys,name)
    if state==2:
        firm=input("Введите фирму: ")
        min_age=int(input("Минимальный возраст: "))
        max_age=int(input("Максимальный возраст: "))
        searchFirmAge(toys,firm,min_age,max_age)
    if state==3:
        name=input("Введите имя: ")
        searchMaxName(toys,name)
```

Входной файл in.txt

```
1;Игрушка1;Фирма1;5;300
2;Игрушка2;Фирма2;6;301
3;Игрушка3;Фирма3;7;302
4;Игрушка4;Фирма2;8;302
5;Игрушка5;Фирма5;5;304
6;Игрушка6;Фирма6;6;302
7;Игрушка7;Фирма7;7;310
8;Игрушка8;Фирма2;8;311
9;Игрушка1;Фирма3;5;3200
10;Игрушка2;Фирма3;6;400
11;Игрушка2;Фирма2;7;500
12;Игрушка2;Фирма3;8;600
13;Игрушка3;Фирма3;5;700
14;Игрушка4;Фирма6;6;800
15;Игрушка5;Фирма7;7;900
16;Игрушка6;Фирма2;8;300
17;Игрушка7;Фирма3;5;302
```

Comment: Спасибо за старание, но к сожалению, задача подразумевает код с использованием словарей(

Answer (score 0):

Думаю эту задачу надо решать с помощью json

Спасибо вам за задачу, так как в первый раз серьёзно посидел и немного подтянул json

Модули используются встроенные ( ничего устанавливать не надо ).
Но надо доработать программу, чтоб выводились все данные с одинаковой ценой или возрастом, а не первые, на которые наткнулась программа. 
Так же чтоб у вас все работало нужно сначала через редактор кода добавить в код `create_new_file()` перед тем как начинается клиентский код. затем активируйте программу и прервите её выполнения введя рандомное число больше 8. Потом уберите строчку `create_new_file()` из кода, чтоб данные которые вы добавите не стирались.

[Как дописывать информацию в json файл на python](https://python-scripts.com/question/8461)

[JSON в Python](https://python-scripts.com/json)

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

def create_new_file():
    """
    перезаписывает файл. т.е вызвав эту функцию все данные которые были в списках обнулятся.
    """

    data = {
     'code': [],
     'name': [],
     'firm': [],
     'age': [],
     'price': []
    }

    with open('data_file.json', 'w+') as write_file:
        json.dump(data, write_file)

def add_data():
    """
    Добавить данные
    """

    code_input = int(input('code: '))
    name_input = str(input('name: '))
    firm_input = str(input('firm: '))
    age_input = int(input('age: '))
    price_input = float(input('price: '))

    path = Path('data_file.json')
    json_data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

    json_data['code'].append(code_input)
    json_data['name'].append(name_input)
    json_data['firm'].append(firm_input)
    json_data['age'].append(age_input)
    json_data['price'].append(price_input)

    path.write_text(json.dumps(json_data), encoding='utf-8')


def find_by_code():
    code_value = int(input("type code and we'll show you all the toys with current code.. "))
    # ВЫГРУЖАЕМ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ JSON ФАЙЛА
    path = Path('data_file.json')
    json_data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

    code_list = json_data['code']
    cur_index = code_list.index(code_value)

    return ' code = {}\n name = {}\n firm = {}\n age = {}\n price = {}'.format(json_data['code'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['name'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['firm'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['age'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['price'][cur_index])


def find_by_name():
    name_value = str(input("type name and we'll show you all the toys with current name.. "))
    # ВЫГРУЖАЕМ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ JSON ФАЙЛА
    path = Path('data_file.json')
    json_data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

    name_list = json_data['name']
    cur_index = name_list.index(name_value)

    return ' code = {}\n name = {}\n firm = {}\n age = {}\n price = {}'.format(json_data['code'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['name'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['firm'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['age'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['price'][cur_index])

def find_by_firm():
    firm_value = str(input("type firm and we'll show you all the toys with current firm.. "))
    # ВЫГРУЖАЕМ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ JSON ФАЙЛА
    path = Path('data_file.json')
    json_data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

    firm_list = json_data['firm']
    cur_index = firm_list.index(firm_value)

    return ' code = {}\n name = {}\n firm = {}\n age = {}\n price = {}'.format(json_data['code'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['name'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['firm'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['age'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['price'][cur_index])

def find_by_age():
    age_value = int(input("type age and we'll show you all the toys with current age.. ")) 
    # ВЫГРУЖАЕМ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ JSON ФАЙЛА
    path = Path('data_file.json')
    json_data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

    age_list = json_data['age']
    cur_index = age_list.index(age_value)

    return ' code = {}\n name = {}\n firm = {}\n age = {}\n price = {}'.format(json_data['code'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['name'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['firm'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['age'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['price'][cur_index])

def find_by_price():
    price_value = float(input("type price and we'll show you all the toys with current price.. ")) 
    # ВЫГРУЖАЕМ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ JSON ФАЙЛА
    path = Path('data_file.json')
    json_data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

    price_list = json_data['price']
    cur_index = price_list.index(price_value)

    return ' code = {}\n name = {}\n firm = {}\n age = {}\n price = {}'.format(json_data['code'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['name'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['firm'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['age'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['price'][cur_index])

def find_the_cheapest():
    # ВЫГРУЖАЕМ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ JSON ФАЙЛА
    path = Path('data_file.json')
    json_data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

    price_list = json_data['price']

    min_price = min(price_list) # Узнать минимальную цену
    cur_index = price_list.index(min_price) # Индекс элемента с минимальной ценой

    return ' code = {}\n name = {}\n firm = {}\n age = {}\n price = {}'.format(json_data['code'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['name'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['firm'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['age'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['price'][cur_index])

def find_the_most_expensive():
    # ВЫГРУЖАЕМ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ JSON ФАЙЛА
    path = Path('data_file.json')
    json_data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))

    price_list = json_data['price']

    max_price = max(price_list) # Узнать максимальную цену
    cur_index = price_list.index(max_price) # Индекс элемента с максимальной ценой

    return ' code = {}\n name = {}\n firm = {}\n age = {}\n price = {}'.format(json_data['code'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['name'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['firm'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['age'][cur_index],
                                                                                json_data['price'][cur_index])

# ==============
# Клиентский код
# ==============

print('Hello BigBoss!')
def print_start():

    print('\n\nEnter 1 to add new toys')
    print('Enter 2 to find by code')
    print('Enter 3 to find by name')
    print('Enter 4 to find by firm')
    print('Enter 5 to find by age')
    print('Enter 6 to find by price')
    print('Enter 7 to find The Cheapest Toy')
    print('Enter 8 to find The Most Expensive One')
    print('If You Wanna Leave Enter Anything else')


print_start()
choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))

while choice == 1 or choice == 2 or choice == 3 or choice == 4 or choice == 5 or choice == 6 or choice == 7 or choice == 8:
    if choice == 1:
        add_data()
        print_start()
        choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))
    if choice == 2:
        print(find_by_code())
        print_start()
        choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))
    if choice == 3:
        print(find_by_name())
        print_start()
        choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))
    if choice == 4:
        print(find_by_firm())
        print_start()
        choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))
    if choice == 5:
        print(find_by_age())
        print_start()
        choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))
    if choice == 6:
        print(find_by_price())
        print_start()
        choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))
    if choice == 7:
        print(find_the_cheapest())
        print_start()
        choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))
    if choice == 8:
        print(find_the_most_expensive())
        print_start()
        choice = int(input('\nSo What You Gonna Do? '))
else:
    print('See You Latter Boss!')
```

Comment: К сожалению, задачу нужно решить именно с использованием словарей( Но всё равно спасибо за старание!

Answer (score 0):

Тебе следует разбить задачу на составные части.

Во первых, тебе нужно смоделировать, какие данные ты хочешь получить. Ты это уже сделал. Тебе нужны: код товара, наименование товара, возрастное ограничение, фирма производитель и стоимость. Теперь можешь представить, что ты составляешь табличку, и перечисленные названия - это колонки в табличке.
Можно создать переменную с именами колонок.

```
field_names = ['age', 'code', 'name', 'firm', 'price']  # порядок можешь выбрать сам
```

Во вторых, необходимо собрать информацию об игрушках из стандартного ввода(функция input). Здесь можно подумать о количестве вводимых игрушек. Сколько игрушек должно поступить в твою программу? Можешь спросить об этом у пользователя.

```
n = int(input("Введите количество игрушек: "))  # преобразуем в число
```

Теперь ты должен определиться куда эти игрушки нужно складывать. Ты упомянул, что задачу нужно решить на словарях, ну что ж, это вполне подходящая структура.
Создаешь переменную toys и устанавливаешь ее списком. Она будет хранить в себе словари с введенными данными.

```
toys = []
```

В цикле спрашиваешь всю необходимую информацию у пользователя, столько раз, сколько было введено в переменной n.

```
for i in range(n):
    toy = {}
    toy['code'] = input("Введите код товара: ")
    toy['name'] = input("Введите наименование товара: ")
    toy['firm'] = input("Введите фирму-производитель: ")
    toy['age'] = input("Введите возрастное ограничение: ")
    toy['price'] = int(input("Введите стоимость: "))  # преобразуем в число
    toys.append(toy)
```

Теперь, когда информация собрана, нужно записать данные в табличку. Для этого подойдет модуль csv встроенный в питон
Его нужно сначала импортировать

```
import csv
```

Открываешь файл на запись:

```
with open('toys.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=',', fieldnames=field_names)
    writer.writeheader()  # Запись названий столбцов
    writer.writerows(toys)  # запись всех данных из списка словарей
```

Минимальное и максимальное значение цены я думаю ты и сам сможешь посчитать. Удачи!

Comment: Благодарю за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Pavlov Ivan ISPspk-218 Lab 4 Variant 10
slovar = dict()
f = open("text.txt", 'r',encoding="utf-8")
for line in f :
    k = line[:6]
    line = line[7:]
    slovar[k] = line
f.close()

for el in slovar:
    print(slovar[el],end='')

m = 1
print("\nДобро пожаловать в магазин игрушек 'PavlovToys'!")
while m != 0 :    
    print(
    """
    Магазин игрушек

    0 - Выход
    1 - Список всех фирм-производителей
    2 - Поиск товара по фирме-производителю
    3 - Поиск товара по наименованию товара и диапазону цены
    """
    )
    m = int(input())
    if m == 1:
        k = 0
        for el in slovar:
            p = slovar[el].find('/')
            firm = slovar[el][p+1:]
            p = firm.find('/') 
            firm = firm[:p]
            k +=1
            print(k,firm)
    elif m == 2:
        f_P = input('Введите фирму-поставщика')

        k = 0
        for el in slovar:
            p = slovar[el].find('/')
            firm = slovar[el][p+1:]
            p = firm.find('/') 
            firm = firm[:p]
            if firm.find(f_P) != -1 :
                k += 1
                print(k,slovar[el])
        if k == 0 : print('Такого поставщика не нашли!')
        elif m == 3 :
        n_T   = input('Введите наименование товара ')
        min_Z = float(input('Введите нижнюю границу цены '))
        max_Z = float(input('Введите верхнюю границу цены '))
        k = 0
        for el in slovar:
            line = slovar[el][:]
            p = line.find('/')
            tovar = line[:p]
            line = line[p+1:]
            p = line.find('/') 
            line = line[p+1:]
            p = line.find('/') 
            zena = float(line[:p])
            if (tovar.find(n_T) != -1) and ( min_Z< zena < max_Z):
                k += 1
                print(k,slovar[el])
        if k == 0 : print('Такой записи не нашли!')
    elif m == 0:
        input('\n\nНажмите Enter для выхода')
    else:
        print('Пожалуйста, выберите 1 из пунктов:')
```